# Olive oil compared to Torah

Tags: sources-mekorot, oil

Is there any source that makes a reference or compares *olive oil* to *torah*?

Comment: While we're at it, do any compare the _torah_ to [Gram-positive bacteria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram-positive_bacteria)?

Comment: @Double well if you pronounce monera wrong than we have something to talk about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> הרואה שמן זית בחלום יצפה למאור תורה שנאמר (שמות כז, כ) ויקחו אליך שמן זית זך
>   [ברכות נז א](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A0%D7%96_%D7%90)

Slightly less explicitly, since olive oil was directly associated with light back then:
e.g.

> אמר רב יהודה אורה זו תורה וכן הוא אומר (משלי ו, כג) כי נר מצוה ותורה אור
>   [מגילה טז](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%98%D7%96_%D7%91)

See also: http://wikivort.co.il/view.php?vort=1563